# Listener of the NetInfo works just one time on react-native

Tags: react-native

When the component is mount the NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener works, but when I enter in another page and back to the first component, being that, I reset de stack of pages, the NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener don't works

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBPzI.png)

Comment: Have the checked whether the first component unmounts during this transisition

Comment: In the componentWillUnmount I put the code NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener, but don't works

Comment: Trying putting console.log to check whether the component really gets unmounted. Then can you please add some code?

Comment: I checked and the componentWillUnmount worked, I add a link to the code image

Comment: Add your code in StackOverflow instead of an Image. Can you add console.log in componentwillunmount and then check the debugger.